# Debugging typescript in VS2017 using Angular template with Webpack

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-2017, typescript2.0

As I understand I should be able to debug Typescript files within Visual Studio 2017.

I've created a new web application using the *Angular* template. When I build my project it creates a minified `js` file including a `.map` file in the `wwwroot`.

Then when I run my application (in IE) I expect that my breakpoint in the `.ts` file should be hit when I navigate to that page. But it says:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

What could be the problem?